# How to set application in web2py to be the 'root'?

Tags: web2py

I googled with no avail, how can i change web2py configuration so when i navigate to www.mydomain.com I see a specific web app (instead of having to go to  www.mydomain.com/mywebapp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help, just customize to your needs: http://code.google.com/p/web2py/source/browse/routes.example.py
also checkout this simple explanation:
http://www.web2py.com/AlterEgo/default/show/42

Answer (score 1):

Look at the web2py documentation about using routes.py . Don't forget to click in 'reload routes' button on admin application.